# Palindrome code in rust programming language

Tags: rust

I am trying to write a palindrome program in Rust.
Even when the input is a palindrome word, my attempt is not showing a palindrome:

```
use std::io;
fn main(){
    println!("enter a word to know if palindrome or not");
    let mut inp=String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut inp).expect("needed a string");
    let  arr:Vec<_>=inp.chars().collect();
    let mut new_st=String::new();
    for i in 0..arr.len(){
        new_st.push(arr[arr.len()-1-i]);
    }
    
    if inp.eq(&new_st[1..]) {
        println!("Palindrome");
    }
    else{
        println!("not a palindrome..");
    }
    println!("{}",&new_st[1..]);
}
```

Output:

```
enter a word to know if palindrome or not
amma
not a palindrome..
amma
```

Comment: After `read_line` your string will include the newline character. You probably want to ignore that in your palindrome check.

Comment: @perivesta that's why Iam comparing the string from second (1) index

Comment: But you're not removing the newline from `inp`

Comment: Here's a debugging tip: do a debug print of your variables to check whether they are what you're expecting. eg, `println!("{inp:?}")` will show you what the actual content of the string is.

Comment: @Herohtar May I know how to do that

Comment: You can either use a range, similar to what you are doing with `new_st[1..]`, or since you're working with `String`s, you can just use the `pop()` method before anything else.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `.read_line()` function does not remove the `\n` that you entered at the end of `inp`. You could remove it from the string using `pop` or use the `.trim()` method on the String to strip out any newline or whitespace characters at the beginning or end.

```rust
inp = inp.trim().to_string();
```

Just some more improvement on your code, you should leverage Rust's iterators to reverse the String faster rather than manually doing it.

You can write this:-

```
let rev = inp.chars().rev().collect::<String>();
```

This iterates over all the characters in the `inp` string and reverses them in order. Finally it collects them into a String that is stored in the `rev` variable.

Also, you should use `==` rather than using the `.eq()` operator, it's just much more clearer.

[See this playground link for complete code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9f8f761a49d89fc6f55f636d4a2d4fa3)